# R RefClass Using fields containing initialize with stop criteria/ avoid call to initialize

Tags: r, oop

Probably I just do not understand how RefClasses work, but is there a way to initialize fields in a class in the constructor/initialize method and not before? See the example below, where when i try to build get the error:

> Error in .Object$initialize(...) : a or b must be provided

```
A <- setRefClass("A",
     fields = list(
       m_a = "numeric",
       m_b = "character"
     ),
     methods = list(
      initialize = function(t_a,t_b,...){
        if(missing(t_a) && missing(t_b)){
          stop("a or b must be provided")
        }
        if(!missing(t_a)){
          m_a <<- t_a
        }
        if(!missing(t_b)){
          m_b <<- t_b
        }
      }
      )
)


B <- setRefClass("B",
     fields = list(
       m_c = "A"
     ),
     methods = list(
       initialize = function(t_c,...){
          m_c <<- A(t_a=1)
       }
     )
)

bTest <- B(TRUE)
```

Comment: Can we remove the "s4" tag? refClasses are different things than S4.

Comment: I removed the tag, but a answer to this issue would still be nice...

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help... I know a lot about S4 but comparatively little about refclasses! (You could perhaps add the "ref" or "reference" tag to it, and it might get seen by the right people. R6 is also a very similar system, so if you tag it with R6 you might attract the right sorts of experts)